# moving between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Basically I have 4 ordinary view controllers, with one of them being the 'home' view controller which holds the main content. The other three are used for checking notifications, creating new content etc. The problem is this - I only want to load the home view controller once (when the app starts up), so when I navigate between the view controllers, to get to the 'home' controller I simply remove the current controller from view with

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

This means the home controller always has to stay behind the current controller. So to summarise everything - When moving from home to any other of the three controllers, I load the controller with

```
UIViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RepliesView"];
                         [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and when I move from any of the three controller to home I dismiss the current view controller. This is fine if I keep moving between home and one other controller, but problems arise when I move from a view controller which is not home to a view controller which is also not home, so basically loading a controller while needing to then dismiss the current one so that the one that is loaded has the home controller directly behind (and can therefore be dismissed to go to home). So far I have tried dismissing and then presenting

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                     UIViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RepliesView"];
                     [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

but this gives the 'view is not in the window hierarchy!' warning and the view that appears is not the one that is being instantiated but the home view. It would be awesome if anyone could suggest a solution

Comment: That problem is that you can't present from a view controller you just dismissed, so you'll either have to present the view from your home view or instead of dismissing then presenting, you can simply present the 2nd view, but dismiss two view controllers at once when you'd like to go back.

Comment: so is there a way I can dismiss a view controller from a different view controller, e.g. not [self dismissView...] but [aViewController dismiss...] ?

Comment: I think you should just present 2 in a row then dismiss directly to the home view controller.

Comment: Because going back two view controllers can be done in one step whereas going backwards then forwards can not.

Comment: Is the home view controller the first view controller?

Comment: Add a containerView in HomeViewController and switch the view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into this a bit and done some experiments on my own and it seems as to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish you shouldn't be using modal view controllers, but should instead add your views directly to the navigation stack. Instead of `presentViewController:` and `dismissViewController:`, use `pushViewController:` and `popViewController`.

So to keep the original intention of your code, you can push to any view controller from your home view using:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RepliesView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

then dismiss using either using

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

or using

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

from any view controller in the stack as long as your "home" view controller is the root view controller.

Then to dismiss and immediately present in the way you're currently trying to do, you can push than immediately pop from a retained copy of the stack:

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RepliesView"];
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

and as long as you don't want to animate the transition, this should work.

If you do want to animate the transition, I'd recommend, immediately pushing to `vc` then performing `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` when you're ready to return to the "home" view.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've done anything wrong, but I can't seem to get this working. I set the home view controller as root controller in the appDelegate, and when I try to pop a view controller to go back to home nothing seems to happen (so the transition never takes place).

Comment: @RodMatveev Are you using pushViewController for your transitions?

Comment: Not for moving back to home as I thought that you had to use popViewController to remove current controller and get to home controller.

Comment: @RodMateev Oh, I see why you're confused... I forgot to change the code from `presentViewController` to `pushViewController`. Updated. Yes, you have to use `popViewController` or `popToRootViewController` to go back to the home view, but also anywhere in your code where you have `presentViewController` has to be changed to `pushViewController`.

Comment: @RodMatveev Specifically, `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];`

Comment: @RodMatveev Did you update your code as recommended? (This solution definitely works... I tested it on my own.)

Comment: yep, everything works really well now :D (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: @RodMatveev OK, great. Glad to hear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this will work, but give this a try:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    UIViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RepliesView"];
    [self.parentViewController presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

You're having an issue because you're trying to present a vc from a vc that has already been dismissed. But if you present it from the dismissed vc's parent vc, that might do that trick

EDIT:
Also not sure if this will work as its a little hacky, but it's worth a shot. In each of your view controllers that are not home, dismiss them like so:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    UIViewController *vc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RepliesView"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewControllerDidDismiss" object:vc];
}];
```

And in your home view controller, listen for the notificaiton:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"ViewControllerDidDismiss"
                                                  object:nil
                                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                              usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                                  UIViewController *vc = [note object];
                                                  [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
                                              }];
```

Comment: I've tried this, but like before the 'home' controller appears instead of 'RepliesView'

Comment: @RodMatveev I came up with another idea for you to try that goes from a bit of a different approach. See my edit

Comment: this does work but you can actually see the home controller before repliesView appears (it kinda flashes for about half a second), is there a way I can deal with this?

Comment: actually it only seems to flash on the first cycle, when I go through your code a second time the flash is shorter and after that repliesView loads directly...

Comment: play around with it and see what you can figure out. i'm not sure how you would prevent it from flashing, that's kinda just the consequence of the inconsistent navigation flow.. I don't have an implementation for this off the top of my head, but maybe programmatically take a screenshot of the view you're going to from home, overlay it in an imageview on home, and when you dismiss the new view, the screenshot will make it look like it's still there. Then do the same for the other views, and hide the image view when returning home for good